# Everytime i load my project, the material is missing

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I just started to learn blender few days ago,I follow BlenderGuru and made some donuts, but everytime i load my project, this donut bread material is missing. I did save a UVunwrapped texture and ColorTexture in jpg type, but I can't seem to load the texture back to my project, is there something i need to do to fix the material on the object?

[image: Before exit the project]
[image: Everytime I load the same project]

Comment: Looks like the bread texture is working just fine on your donut material, according to your screenshot. Are you concerned about that matte-black object in the background? Select it in the viewport and click the top tab that says "Shading" to look at the material nodes for that object. You will see what looks like a few menus (nodes) connected by "noodles". Go through all the Texture nodes and re-locate the image files manually to ensure the program is looking in the right place.

Comment: Whenever you load a .blend file it gets rid of un-used materials / images. You should make sure something is actually using those materials, otherwise you can click the F button to save them even if they have no users.

Comment: Can't you locate the texture image in your file browser?

Comment: @hatinacat2000 oh sorry, that 1st image is my main project that i havent exit since morning, the bottom one is what happen when i load the project

Comment: @InTheBeef I tried that just now, the material is saved in the project but the object still appear as purple.

Comment: @FFeller I can't, even though I browse and linked the texture back to the Material Base Color slot, the material just appear as white color and my viewport donut appear as purple. The purple color will go away only when I remove the Image Texture in Shader Editor

Comment: Did you save the picture after the texture painting?

Comment: @FFeller I did save it into jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can "pack" the image into the .blend file so that you don't have to worry about the external files moving around. You do do this from the image editor, under the "image" dropdown menu (pack is the last option).

Keep in mind that it will actually save the image into the blend file, so if you did this with, say, a 10mb png file, and you save multiple versions of the blend file, they will all include the 10mb png as well.

Comment: You can also do this from the main menu: "External Data" -> "Pack Resources"